# MacBook Pro OSX 10.6.8 - iPhone SE

Tags: iphone

I just bought an iPhone SE and I want to synchronize it with my iTunes library but when I connect the iPhone to my Mac I get a message saying that the iPhone can't be used because it requires a later iTunes version. I have iTunes 11.4 and when I check for updates it says it is the latest. I have O.S. 10.6.8 and would like **not** to upgrade to the next generation as some programs are not compatible any more. Do I have an option? Thank you

Comment: I meant OSX 10.6.5 and NOT 10.6.8 !!

Comment: so you should edit the question and not add a comment + why not upgrade to 10,6.8

Comment: Simple answer is you need a newer iTunes which only runs on a  newer OS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple Support Site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7548072?start=0&tstart=0):

> The SE requires iTunes 12.3.3 and in order to get it you will have to
>   update OS X to El Capitan. This is how Apple designed it for better or
>   worse, sorry.

Your iTunes IS in fact the latest version on THAT OS but not the latest overall.

Comment: The reason I am postponing upgrading to El Capitan or later is because Filemaker 7 is incompatible with that OS. Is it possible to transfer data from FM 7 to a later version compatible with the later OS?

Comment: According to [this](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10571/~/converting-older-filemaker-pro-files-to-the-.fmp12-file-format), it should be no problem.  
> If your current version of FileMaker Pro is 15, 14, 13, 12 (.fmp 12), or FileMaker Pro 11, 10, 9, 8 or 7 (.fp7), files will convert directly to FileMaker Pro (.fmp12) and there is no additional conversion necessary.

Comment: The version I use of Filemaker Pro is 7.(0v3) and in (help.filemaker.com) only 7.(fp7) is mentioned. Is this relevant?

Comment: as far as I can tell, "fp7" is just the format of the files, whereas 7.0v3 is apparently the version of the programm you're using — I don't use File Maker but it would make sense that all files created with Version 7 use the format "fp7".

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to sync your iTunes library, you *will* have to update it. If you still don't want to do that, you can either borrow a friends' computer or just go to an Apple Store directly and let them do it for you.